# Почему не выходит добраться до div элемента?

Tags: javascript

```js
document.body.firstChild.nextSibiling.style.border = '2px solid red';
```

```html
<body>
  <div>Пользователи:</div>
  <ul>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>1</li>
  </ul>

  <!-- комментарий -->
</body>
```

Почему не работает данный код? Пытаюсь добраться до div'a

Comment: Вот эти два варианта работают: [`.firstChild.nextElementSibiling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling) или [`.firstElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild)

Comment: Потому что `sibling`, а не `sibiling`.

Comment: @diraria `nextElementSibiling` работать не будет, потому что правильно `nextElementSibling`.

Comment: Если это ваш код, то упростите себе жизнь -- навесьте class или id на этот div.

Comment: @Regent, да, спасибо) но я уже не могу изменить комментарий...

Answer (score 3):

```js
document.body.firstElementChild.style.border = '2px solid red';
```

```html
<body>
  <div>Пользователи:</div>
  <ul>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>1</li>
  </ul>

  <!-- комментарий -->
</body>
```